# Perl DBI - transfer data between two sql servers - fetchall_arrayref

Tags: sql, sql-server, perl, dbi, dbix-class

I have 2 servers: dbh1 and dbh2 where I query dbh1 and pull data via fetchall_arrayref method.  Once I execute the query, I want to insert the output from dbh1 into a temp table on server dbh2.

I am able to establish access to both servers at the same time and am able to pull data from both.
1. I pull data from dbh1:

```
while($row = shift(@$rowcache) || shift(@{$rowcache=$sth1->fetchall_arrayref(undef, $max_rows)})) {
        #call to sub insert2tempData
        &insert2tempData(values @{$row});
}
```

2. Then on dbh2 I have an insert query:

```
    INSERT INTO ##population (someid, Type, anotherid)
    VALUES ('123123', 'blah', '634234');
```

Question: 
How can I insert the bulk result of the fetchall_arrayref from dbh1 into the temp table on server dbh2 (without looping through individual records)?

Ok - so i was able to resolve this issue and was able to implement the following code:

```
     my $max_rows = 38;
my $rowcache = [];
my $sum   = 0;

if($fldnames eq "ALL"){ $fldnames = join(',', @{ $sth1->{NAME} });}

my $ins = $dbh2->prepare("insert into $database2.dbo.$tblname2 ($fldnames) values $fldvalues");

my $fetch_tuple_sub = sub { shift(@$rowcache) || shift(@{$rowcache=$sth1->fetchall_arrayref(undef, $max_rows)}) };

my @tuple_status;
my $rc;

$rc = $ins->execute_for_fetch($fetch_tuple_sub, \@tuple_status);

my @errors = grep { ref $_ } @tuple_status;
```

The transfer works but it is still slower than if I were to transfer data manually through SQL Server export/import wizard .  The issue that i notice is that the data flows row by row into the destination and I was wondering if it is possible to increase the bulk transfer size.  It downloads the data extremely fast, but when i combine download and upload then the speeds decreases dramatically and it takes up to 10 minutes to transfer a 5000 row table between servers.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if you said what your goal was (speed?) rather than asking a specific question on avoiding looping.

For a Perl/DBI way:

Look at DBI's [execute_array](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.622/DBI.pm#execute_array) and [execute_for_fetch](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.622/DBI.pm#execute_for_fetch) however as you've not told us which DBD you are using it is impossible to say more. Not all DBDs support bulk insert and when they don't DBI emulates it. DBD::Oracle does and DBD::ODBC does (in recent versions see [odbc_array_operations](http://search.cpan.org/~mjevans/DBD-ODBC-1.39/ODBC.pm#odbc_array_operations)) but in the latter it is off by default.

Comment: I am working with SQL Server and here is a part of my connection string: my $dsn = 'DBI:ODBC:Driver={SQL Server}'; 
I am looking for speed to insert or append results from fetchall_arrayref into a table on another SQL server.

Comment: If you need to do it from Perl then definitely check out the links in my answer and think about whether you can do it in a transaction - as that will speed it up massively.

Comment: thanks! im looking into your links trying to see how i can bulk up individual columns and do it in single transactions

Comment: Is there a way to see if DBD::ODBC is installed on my version? And do you have an example of odbc bulk insert operation that I can leverage?

Comment: perl -MDBD::ODBC -le 'print $DBD::ODBC::VERSION'. There are examples in the t sub directory of an untarred DBD::ODBC of execute_for_fetch/execute_array in the execute_array test.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention which version of SQL Server you are using. First, I would look into the "BULK INSERT" support of that version.

You also didn't mention how many rows are involved. I'll assume that they fit into memory, otherwise a bulk insert won't work.

From there it's up to you to translate the output of `fetchall_arrayref` into the syntax needed for the "BULK INSERT" operation.

Comment: Thanks for yor help! Here are the specs: SQL Server 2008 and im looking to transfer about 10,000 with 3 columns (number of rows might fluctuate)

Comment: What did you find you looked up BULK INSERT support for it? Have you tried to translate the rows you are getting back into an SQL statement in that format?

Comment: im currently trying to translate into arrays to hold entire column and then i would attempt to try testing bulk insert... thanks for your help!  im surprised why no one attempted coding a data transfer between 2 servers in perl...

Comment: There is an example at http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.622/DBI.pm#execute_for_fetch